# Intellisense window using PYQT4

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4

Hi I am trying to learn pyqt by writing my own texteditor, using pyQT one of the things i want to have is intellisense/word suggestions. i.e so that as you type in the text editor it offers you suggestions of words that would be suitable. I have a list of words, and i can already generate a list of suggestions. My difficulty is presenting it, I am unable to bring up a window/dialog at the cursor location which shows a list of possible words. So far I have succesfully got QMenu to work, but it is limited as in it has no scrollbars and can only display a limited number of suggestions.
I tried QListWidget, but this displayed a popup window(complete with max,min buttons) this just isn't right, though it did allow me to have scrollbars.
I would like to know what object I should use to display suggestions to a user at the cursor location just like one sees in any good IDE. This is what I am trying to do
[image: Intellisnese image]

Comment: If you're not coding this just for the fun of it, Scintilla supports such popups (and much more) and has nice Python bindings: http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/qscintilla/intro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some searching, I found that I was thinking about it all wrong.QListview is not what I needed
Scintilla is great, and probably the most appropriate. Thank you rainer
There is a wonderful example in
[Sample using QScintilla with PyQt](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/04/01/sample-using-qscintilla-with-pyqt/)

But that is not all that I found. There is a class QCompleter, which is also quite good, as I can use it with a QTextedit, after a good amount of searching I found. "A text-edit which would help enter long words"
[QTextEdit with autocompletion using pyqt](http://rowinggolfer.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/qtextedit-with-autocompletion-using.html)

Plenty of documentation in
[QCompleter Class Reference](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcompleter.html)